# Modeling data in Redis. Which is better: Sorted set & strings or hash table?

Tags: redis

I want to use redis to store data that is sourced from a sql db. In the db, each row has an ID, date, and value, where the ID and date make up a composite key (there can only be one value for a particular ID and date). An example is below:

```
ID        Date              Value
1         01/01/2001        1.2
1         02/01/2001        1.5
1         04/23/2002        1.5
2         05/05/2009        0.4
```

Users should be able to query this data in redis given a particular ID and date range. For example, they might want all values for 2019 with ID 45. If the user does not specify a start or end time, we use the system's Date.Min or Date.Max respectively. We also want to support refreshing redis data from the database using the same parameters (ID and date range).

Initially, I used a zset:

```
zset key             zset member              score
1                    01/01/2001_1.2           20010101
1                    02/01/2001_1.5           20010201
1                    04/23/2002_1.5           20020423
2                    05/05/2009_0.4           20090505
```

Only, what happens if the value field changes in the db? For instance, ID 1 and date 01/01/2001 might change to 1.3 later on. I would want the original value to be updated, but instead, a new member will be inserted. Rather, I would need to first check that a member for a particular score exists, and delete if it does before inserting a new member. I imagine this could get expensive if refreshing, for example, 10 years worth of data.

I thought of two possible fixes to this:

**1.) Use a zset and string key-value:**

```
zset key             zset value               score
1                    1_01/01/2001             20010101
1                    1_02/01/2001             20010201
1                    1_04/23/2002             20020423
2                    2_05/05/2009             20090505

string key           string value
1_01/01/2001         1.2
1_02/01/2001         1.5
1_04/23/2002         1.5
2_05/05/2009         0.4
```

This allows me to easily update the value, and query for a date range, but adds some complexity as now I need to use two redis data structures instead of 1.

**2.) Use a hash table:**

```
hash key             sub-key                  value
1                    01/01/2001               1.2
1                    02/01/2001               1.5
1                    04/23/2002               1.5
2                    05/05/2009               0.4
```

This is nice because I only have to use 1 data structure and although it would be O(N) to get all values for a particular hash key, solution 1 would have the same drawback when getting values for all string keys returned from the zset.

However, with this solution, I now need to generate all sub-keys between a given start and end date in my calling code, and not every date may have a value. There are also some edge cases that I now need to handle (what if the user wants all values up until today? Do I use HGETALL and just remove the ones in the future I don't care about? At what date range size should I use HGETALL rather than HMGET?)

In my view, there are pro's and con's to each solution, and I'm not sure which one will be easier in the long term to maintain. Does anyone have thoughts as to which structure they would choose in this situation?